# How to apply a pattern created with `grid` to `geom_sf()`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

*Edit:* See PR https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/5

I am failing to apply ggplot2's [new capabilities](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2024/02/ggplot2-3-5-0/) to apply patterns created with the grid package as a fill to geospatial data. What am I doing wrong?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

checkered <- pattern(
  rectGrob(x = c(0.25, 0.75), y = c(0.25, 0.75), width = 0.5, height = 0.5),
  width = unit(5, "mm"), height = unit(5, "mm"), extend = "repeat",
  gp = gpar(fill = "limegreen")
)

# works with non-sf data
ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar(fill = checkered)
```

[image]

```r
# does not work with sf data
china <- spData::world |> filter(iso_a2 == "CN")

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = china, fill = checkered)
#> Error in `geom_sf()`:
#> ! Problem while converting geom to grob.
#> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Unknown colour name: list(f = function () 
#> {
#>     grid.draw(gTree(children = gList(grob), gp = gp), recording = FALSE)
#> }, x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 5, height = 5, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, extend = "repeat", group = TRUE)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-25 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: `geom_sf` is a function in the {sf} package, not {ggplot2}. Probably, this is not prepared yet to support the new pattern capabilities.

Comment: Wrong - `geom_sf` is very definitely part of the `ggplot2` package.

Answer (score 0):

From the release notes: "We are pleased to report that as of this release, patterns can be used as the fill aesthetic in most layers."

"Most" layers in this case does not seem to include `geom_sf` layers. Perhaps file an issue asking for clarification on the ggplot2 github page: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues

Comment: Took liberty of filing issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5716